# Replacements for Full Text Search

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I am not a big fan of Full Text search with MSSQL(not sure if there is another) does anyone know of any other options to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)** from Apache is worth a look.

> After your raw text data has been
>   indexed, you can use Lucene.Net’s API
>   to search this data. Indexing and
>   searching via Lucene.Net’s APIs is
>   easy and yet very powerful.

[Demo and Breakdown](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/BrainDump/Working-with-Lucene-dot-Net/)

Answer (score 2):

Lucene is a low level app. You get all the control, but you have to code quite a bit to make an usable app with it.

Solr is based on Lucene, but gives you a much more friendly http interface. It's very configurable, but it requires some learning to set up.

Sphinx is worth reviewing. It's not the most popular, but has some nice features.

There's a hosted version of Solr, called webSolr, if you don't want to manage your own servers. Still has the same flexibility/learning curve than solar, minus setting up the server.

Last, but my personal preference (completely biased here) is IndexTank. It's hosted like websolr, but has a free plan, works well realtime (sorl may take some tweaking to do that), and allows you to tweak relevance with custom written functions without requiring to reindex.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few replacements out there.  I can't think of the names of any at the moment.

However major improvements were made with Full Text Search in SQL Server 2008.  You may want to look into an upgrade to get the speed improvements.